# Sockets on Native Android Application?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-ndk-r5

i coded a native android executable in FPC that connects to my server and download weather information using sockets (connect/send/recv calls), works ok on my pc, and to run on android, i sent it to both my phone and emulator, then i went to terminal and ran it, it didnt work, just froze.

but after i executed "su" command (not allowed in emulator) and then my application again, it worked !

i got no experience in java, but what do i need to make it a valid application? like the user installs it using .apk file and it works? without terminal or super user?

is this possible?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to turn it into APK like any other Android app. It's probably going to be a lot of work since (from your question) this process is new to you. I would start [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html). Basically you're going through the process like if you were creating a normal app and then adding your native files. Depending on what native libraries you used (besides networking as it's supported natively), you may have to call back into Java through JNI to access those APIs (audio for example in pre 2.3).